# Game Center leaderboard error

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, gamekit

I'm trying to get some leaderboards into my game and I'm getting the follow error:

```
No visible @interface for 'MGLGameCenterManager' declares the selector 'callDelegateOnMainThread:withArg:error:'
```

And it's in here,

```
- (void) authenticateLocalUser
{
if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated)
{
    return;
}

[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
 {
     [self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(processGameCenterAuthentication:) withArg:
      NULL error: error];
 }];
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: the problem is there is no 'callDelegateOnMainThread:withArg:error: selector declared anywhere, particularly in MGLGameCenterManager

Comment: @AndreyChernukha  oh, yeah, it had me create that a little later down in the book. One more thing, the authenticateWithCompletionHandler is deprecated since 6.0 and i now know that setAuthenticateHandler should be used instead, but I'm fiddling with it and getting a lot of errors Can you show me how that part should be re coded.

Answer (score 0):

This is my piece of code for `setAuthenticateHandler:`

```
[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)
    {   
        if (error)
            NSLog(@"Authentication failed %@", error.localizedDescription);
        else
        {
            if (viewController)
                [[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController:viewController
                                                          animated:YES
                                                        completion:nil];
            else
                [self proccessAuthentification];
        }
    };
```